# Can you ellipsize the placeholder of a textarea in one CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, chromium, placeholder

##### I am asking about truncating a *placeholder* on a single line (one row of text) in a *textarea*.

To truncate the placeholder of an `<input>` element, you only need one selector (and only one rule in that selector).

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog">
```

To do the same for a `<textarea>`, you seem to need two selectors in Chromium-based browsers (tested Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Brave), including a *duplicated rule*:

```css
textarea:placeholder-shown {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"></textarea>
```

Firefox and Safari only require one selector, which is what I would expect, although they only work with `::placeholder` (`:placeholder-shown` doesn't work alone).

Am I missing something, or should I consider filing a Chromium bug?